# MYSQL comma separated IDs vs separate table

Tags: mysql

Consider a table `products` which has product details including its category. One product may belong to multiple category so I'm keeping it as a comma separated list of category IDs.

I know this is not normalized approach.

Can any MYSQL expert tell me that which approach will be faster for selecting products of a particular category.

Obviously we have to JOIN `products` table and `products_category_relation` table if take normalized approach.

**AND**

In my approach we have to write a like query to find the products (assume we are searching for category id 10)

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
WHERE p.category like '10' 
OR p.category like '10,%'
OR p.category like '%,10'
OR p.category like '%,10,%'
```

Can any one tell me if this approach is faster or the JOIN approach will be faster?

I know about normalization. I know about other risks involved in my approach. But they do not matter in my case. So, I'm concerned with speed.

Any theoretical explanation about its speed or a practical test result are welcome.

**UPDATE**

I'm using myISAM engine
product table has Primary Key `product_id`
FullText index on `category` column of `products` table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database conforming to the first normal form will be much faster. Your example query cannot use any index and requires a full table scan to resolve. Worse, it must scan the entire text field for all the rows and text work is almost always more expensive than integer work for the computer.

A normalized table can easily use an index on the category column to speed up the query.

Text storage may also require more space on disk since numbers are usually more expensive when saved as characters than as the correct integer type (of course there's some overhead involved in row storage as well).

Comment: "It will also require more space on disk since numbers are usually more expensive when saved as " @EmilVikstrom, I think it is true for big numbers. usually category id do not exceed 3 characters.

Comment: Imdad, in that case, use an `UNSIGNED SMALLINT` which uses 2 bytes and have a range from `0` to `65535`.

Comment: As far as now your answer seems to be better than others. +1

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10',`category`)>0;
```

You can then compare the results vs normalized approach, but this will definitely be more robust than multiple LIKE clauses

Comment: It is more robust and work fine, but speaking of performance this is still slower than a separate table

Answer (score 1):

take the normalized approach.

you haven't given much information about the tables involved, the keys and indexes set on that tables and the engine you're using, but a `JOIN` will be faster in almost any case (much faster than the `like`-mess).